# Report considering changes in picklist value

Tags: reporting, picklist, change

we are a non-profit helping immigrants. We have a custom picklist field showing at which stage our customers are (let's say before the immigration and after the immigration). We need a report that shows how many times we helped our clients (i.e. interactions such as logged calls, emails) before they immigrated and how many times after.
I know there is the possibility of field history tracking, which I enabled. But how can I make use of it for the above mentioned purpose?

Comment: Be explicit about having the software (Salesforce) reflect your process. In this case, you want to log the interaction. Two out of the box choices: Activity (Task or Event) or Case. Create a new record of one of these, then it'll be easy to report on.

Comment: But my question is if I can capture the activities before the immigration and after the immigration? This is indicated with a picklist field. If I make a report and meanwhile have changed a contact's stage from "before immigration" to "after immigration", the report will just take the new current value of the picklist, right? But I need the report to reflect both - activities before and activities after

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: If the only thing that you have to identify before and after a particular stage value is the stage field itself, then you've got an underlying issue with the completeness of the data that you're capturing. It feels like you're going to have to introduce some stamping of dates or of the stage of the client as the activity is captured.